# Splitting a large 2.1 billion rows csv files into smaller files with a column as ID

Tags: python, bash

I have a 1TB `csv` file in the form

```
 id   data1   data2 ...
001      x1      y2
001      x2      y2
002      x1      y1
...     ...     ...
```

I'd like to have a file for each ID as in

```
[001.csv]
001      x1      y2
001      x2      y2

[002.csv]
002      x1      y1
```

The file contains quoted strings and is not ordered by ID. I can run a query to know all the IDs in advance.

What's the best way to do this in the linux command line or python?

Comment: Does your file contain Strings of data, which contain comma's? And is the file ordered by ID? If the answer to the first question is no and to the second question is yes, I can write some easy Java code for you that does this. No guarantees on how long the execution time will be though.

Comment: Do you know all the keys in advance? This sounds like a short loop of parallel `grep`'s.

Answer (score 3):

Try this on command line - awk is great and elegant. ( ensure there are right number of spaces between between the double quotes below - i.e. as as there between id and data1

```sh
$ awk -F"   " '{print >$1".csv"}'  <your_1Tb_file>
```

This will create 001.csv, 002.csv etc files

Edit based on the comment about skipping the first line - may ways you can do it. Here is one - to add a pipe ahead of the awk.

```sh
$ tail +2 <your_1Tb_file> |  awk -F"   " '{print >$1".csv"}'
```

Comment: This is a nice usage of awk. It will create id.csv, however, because it doesn't skip the first line.

Comment: Good point @RobertStiffler - added a pipe with tail before awk. above.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a shell script that will do what you want. I don't know how long this will take to run through 1TB of data, though.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tail -n +2 data.csv | while read -r line; do
    basename=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print $1 }');

    echo "$line" >> "$basename.csv";
done
```

`tail -n +2` - skips the first line of the file

`while read -r line` - loops over each line of the file. Ensure that the file ends with a newline or the last line will be skipped.

`awk '{ print $1 }'` - get's the first fields of each line e.g. `001`, `002`.

`echo "$line" >>` - concatenates the line to the end of the file.

Comment: this will read a TB of records with a `read` loop, which is going to be slow, and will execute a subshell on every line to echo to a separate spawn of `awk`...

Comment: @PaulHodges is there an efficient way to iterate over the lines of a file using bash?

Comment: Indirectly, perhaps. Small files don't matter until the numbers mount. Really big files should use compiled binaries to manage the I/O. Sumit's `awk` solution above is good. Something is `perl` is good. The main thing to me is to get the fewest possible highest efficiency processes reading and writing. A single `awk` is pretty good, whereas a `read` loop would take forever to process a billion lines, especially when spawning a separate `awk` for each, and then making the file system open and close a file on each iteration. Speaking of which - anyone know if `awk` holds those files open?